# Creating doc objects efficiently with a spacy-stanza model

Tags: python, spacy

The most efficient way to create doc objects from a list of texts is the following, according to the creators of `SPACY`:

```
docs = list(nlp(texts))
```

where:

> `nlp` : the trained SPACY model
> `texts` : a list of texts that we want to convert to doc objects
> `docs` : a list of doc objects derived from the list texts

However, when I use this code with a spacy-stanza language model I get an error message:

```
AssertionError: If neither 'pretokenized' or 'no_ssplit' option is enabled, the input to the TokenizerProcessor must be a string.
```

What would be your advice?

Answer (score 0):

The `stanza` library doesn't have a good solution for batching, so `nlp.pipe()` with a stanza model isn't going to help the performance like it would with a spacy model.

The stanza developers' only suggestion is to use `"\n\n"` to separate texts, process them as one text, and then deal with splitting the predictions back into individual docs afterwards. On the spacy side of things, `span.as_doc()` might be helpful if you can identify the token indices where each document starts and ends, so:

```py
span = huge_doc[start_token_index:end_token_index]
single_doc = span.as_doc()
```

Be aware that if the start/end indices are in the middle of a parse rather than at a sentence boundary, `span.as_doc()` will make adjustments that will change the original analysis so that the single doc has a valid parse.